# Function as parameter

Tags: typescript

This is the function called:

```
    protected buildAggregation(
                collection: Collection<DDHRecordSingleOrigin>,
                aggCollection: Collection<DDHRecord>,
                reverse: boolean = false,
                additionalGroupingIdFields: { [k: string]: string } = {},
                timeDimField: string = "$time_dim",
                timeDimValueField = "$time_dim_value",
                extrasProvider: (
                    record: DDHAggregationRecord
                ) => { [key: string]: any } = (_d) => {
                    return {};
                },
                fixCountryGroup: (group: string[]) => string[] | undefined = (_x) =>
                    undefined
            ): number {
```

and this is the caller:

```
    c += this.buildAggregation(
                self.tempRecordsSingleOrigin,
                self.dstCollection,
                false,
                {
                    age: "$extras.age",
                    sex: "$extras.sex",
                    c_citizen: "$extras.c_citizen"
                },
                "$time_dim",
                "$time_dim_value",
                idExtra,
                fixCountryGroup
            );
```

and this is another caller, without the fixCountryGroup parameter:

```
    c += this.buildAggregation(
                self.tempRecordsSingleOrigin,
                self.dstCollection,
                false,
                {
                    age: "$extras.age",
                    sex: "$extras.sex",
                    c_citizen: "$extras.c_citizen"
                },
                "$time_dim",
                "$time_dim_value",
                idExtra
            );
            );
```

How to check, in the called function, the fixCountryGroup parameter is undefined?
With

```
    if (fixCountryGroup !== undefined) {
        groups = fixCountryGroup(groups)!;
       }

       if (typeof fixCountryGroup !== undefined) {
        groups = fixCountryGroup(groups)!;
       }
```

the if is alway true: fixCountryGroup: undefined - Typeof: function
The type is "function"

Comment: Consider editing the code in this question to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), where the only issues present are the ones you're asking about.  Right now, types like `DDHAggregationRecord` are not defined.  If the issue in your question does not depend on `DDHAggregationRecord`, then it should be removed from the question.  If the issue does depend on it, the definition should be included.

Comment: On first glance it looks like you are providing a default value for `fixCountryGroup`, so it will never be `undefined` inside the implementation.  Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFAQwFyIM5QE4xgDmiAvIgEQAiAogGICCAqgDIAqFAlIgN4CwAKETDEEBNjgAbAKYA6SXCLoANIjRlS5cABNpwQtO2cA3IIC+gwagoALaXmldjiAPQvEdh8jSTs0qygmru60jKxs3r7+Aqg6egZGzm6IoczskX5AA).  If that is your issue I will write up the answer, but you should consider modifying your question to remove all unrelated issues

Comment: @jcalz: that's the point: if I remove the default in the fixCountryGroup parameter of the method protected buildAggregation, I've got the error: "An argument for 'fixCountryGroup' was not provided" in the this.buildAggregation call without the fixCountryGroup parameter (the second call to buildAggregation).

Comment: Yes, if you remove the default then the parameter becomes required unless you mark it as optional.  I’m afraid I don’t understand the issue; ideally you will modify your code to be a [mcve] so I can see for myself what your problem might be.

Comment: @jcalz: thanks, resolved with optional parameter.